# When not bundling, is there any way to filter the libraries copied with copyWorkboxLibraries?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm building my project with npm scripts and node so I'm using `workbox-build` and calling `copyWorkboxLibraries` in a script and then in my SW I'm calling `importScripts` with the path set in `setConfig`.  Is there any way to copy fewer than all of the workbox libraries or is it up to the developer to remove what isn't needed?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in the build script:

```js
const pkgs = [
  'workbox-core',
  'workbox-sw',
];

copyWorkboxLibraries('./docs')
  .then(s => {
    console.log(`Workbox libraries available in ${s}.`);
    return s;
  })
  .then(async d => {
    const dir = await fs.opendir(path.resolve('./docs/' + d));
    for await (const dirent of dir) {
      if (!pkgs.some(pk => dirent.name.includes(pk))) {
        fs.unlink(path.resolve('./docs/' + d + '/' + dirent.name));
      }
    }
  });
```

This will remove every file whose name doesn't start with `workbox-core` or `workbox-sw` from the `workbox-v[version]` folder that you will be deploying along with your SW.